# django creating models inside of form for manytomany field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm making recipes website and therefore I have recipe model for which I want to create form that looks like this:

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    ....
    products = models.ManyToManyField(ProductMeasurement)
    ....
```

And I have ProductMeasurement model and form already:

```
class ProductMeasurement(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    measurement = models.ForeignKey(Measurement)
    value = models.FloatField()

 class FridgeForm(forms.Form):
    product = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=None, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    amount = forms.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    measurement = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=None, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FridgeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['product'].queryset = Product.objects.all()
        self.fields['measurement'].queryset = Measurement.objects.all()
```

What I want to do is create form for Recipe model. The problem is that there's not going to be already ProductMeasurements that user wants for his recipe. Therefore I need to find a way so that user can create ProductMeasurement inside of Recipe form. What are possible approaches here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

django formsets was what I was looking for.